# Push notifications doesn't work on iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Push notifications doesn't work on iOS 5.0.1. I have a development SSL certificate for the push notifications on my server. Do i need a distribution certificate for push notification to work on the builds signed with an distribution adhoc provisioning profile? They work fine when i test the app on my iPod which has the development provisioning profile. I hope i am able to explain my problem :(

Comment: see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406863/iphone-push-notification-certificates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a distribution certificate for ad-hoc builds and appstore builds. The distribution certificate has to be associated with the production push certificate for the right app id.

I found that this guide was a huge help in getting started http://code.google.com/p/apns-php/wiki/CertificateCreation